# R session crashes when using .so file that uses OpenBLAS

Tags: c++, r

I tried to write some simple matrix calculation code in c++ with OpenBLAS and then import my program into R. I did not use any Rcpp related things.

When compiled alone, the c++ program works perfectly. When I commented the few lines with OpenBLAS functions, used `R CMD SHLIB` to compile it and used `dyn.load` to import the .so file into my R program, R works fine.

However, if I uncommented the OpenBLAS-involved part, R crashes every time. When run from terminal, the following error message was reported:

```
R(90544,0x16bd7f000) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x6000033d0620
*** Incorrect guard value: 0
R(90544,0x16bd7f000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      R
```

Also, when I run only with a single line of OpenBLAS command, there was the following error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x60012e797320, cause 'invalid permissions'
```

Do I miss something? I do need some help since I struggled with this for a long time. Thank you guys.

Comment: R itself has been calling `dgemm` since the very beginning, just see `src/main/array.c` in the R sources.  Now, they do it via Fortran but you could make your life a _lot_ easier by relying e.g. on the C++ abstractions in Armadillo. It gives you all of BLAS and LAPACK without having to add or change one line in the setup.  And if you don't like the Rcpp interface you can just ignore it. Or you can use it and get easy access -- see my `fastLm()` wrapper in the README and sources.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way round. I directly use the LAPACK used by R and followed the procedure stated here medium.com/@shiansu/calling-blas-in-r-the-hard-way-da90e0206d99. With some slight adaption, my code could finally work.

---

It is suggested that it might be better to add the corresponding code to my answer. A sample c code for matrix multiplication is as follows:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP mat_mul_blas(SEXP A_, SEXP B_, SEXP m_, SEXP n_, SEXP k_) {
    double* A = REAL(A_);
    double* B = REAL(B_);

    int m = asInteger(m_);  // The number of rows in A
    int n = asInteger(n_);  // The number of columns in B
    int k = asInteger(k_);  // The number of columns in A and rows in B

    char* transa = "N";
    char* transb = "N";

    double alpha = 1.0;
    double beta = 0.0;

    SEXP RES_;
    RES_ = PROTECT(allocMatrix(REALSXP, m, n));
    double* RES = REAL(RES_);

    F77_NAME(dgemm)
    (transa, transb, &m, &n, &k, &alpha, A, &m, B, &k, &beta, RES, &m);

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return (RES_);
}
```

In order to compile the c file into so file, we might need to run the following command in the terminal

```
R CMD SHLIB xxx.c
```

In order to make the compilation smooth, we may need to configure the `Makeconf` file. For my case, it is under the directory `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/etc/Makeconf` and I believe it varies among different computers.

I hope this more detailed answer is helpful for others with a similar question.

Comment: Thank you for moving the comment to the answer. However, please add to your answer the code - at best with the slight adaption - for future reference. The medium post could be gone somewhere in the future. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @StefanBollmann Hi! I added more details to my answer.

Comment: I would go with `Rcpp::cppFunction("arma::mat mm(const arma::mat& A, const arma::mat& B) { return A * B; }", depends="RcppArmadillo")`.  One statement, given two matrices.  Deals with everything, still calls DGEMM from whichever BLAS/LAPACK your R is wired with (can be OpenBLAS, MKL, ...) and _will work as the same one line on every R installation_ (that has RcppArmadillo and hence a compiler setup).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi! Thanks for pointing it out. What if I need to have the BLAS/LAPACK function interacting with other functions written in c and even use some other c headers?

Comment: Nothing, really.  You get the same BLAS and LAPACK headers.  You can concentrate on that at the C level (`double* ptr, int n`) or rely on C++.  (Rcpp)Armadillo will make it a breeze to connect back to R as it has the glue.  Your inner algos can just use C and C++ as you like.  The key really is that _R already links with LAPACK and BLAS and always has_.  (There was a caveat that R used to also build with its own copy of LAPACK/BLAS, always on Windows, optionally elswhere--and that copy had a subset lacking eg complex-value functions. But that changed a few R releases ago and is complete now.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you so much. Another question that bothered me is that (I am not familar with how Rcpp works, sorry...) -- if I want to change some compilation options, is the Makeconf file the file to change as well?

Comment: In your local package you can (should, really) use `src/Makevars` instead.  And feel free to come to the rcpp-devel list, we gladly help on full example there too.